# Enter Filename missing in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have a weird problem in Visual Studio 2017. Whenever I create a New File From The File Menu or Ctrl+N The File Name option is not present in the dialog(see screenshot). However when I Add a file(Ctrl+Shift+A) from the Context Menu in Solution Browser, the option is present.[image: Screen Shot from New option]

Comment: Click the arrow next to open and select new?

Comment: It has always worked this way.  You'll be prompted to provide a name when you save the file.

Answer (score 0):

The "File New" option allows you to create "temporary" in memory files. Which is very useful. After creating the file you can save it by hitting save as and putting it where you want it with the name you want it to have,